# Irreducible minimal polynomial of a quaternion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, minimal-polynomials

Let $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{H})$ be a matrix with complex spectrum where $ \mathbb{H} $ is quaternions set. I want to prove $A$ is triangularizable. In fact, I want to prove every quaternionic matrix is triangularizable.

To this end, since minimal polynomial of $A$ exists, so it's enough to show that its minimal polynomial is reducible.

I want use contradiction. If the minimal polynomial is irreducible, then what's the form? 
And How do I get a contradiction?

Comment: Did you really consider what all those terms you use mean when working over a skew field? In that situation multiplication by a non-central scalar (here for instance a non-real complex number) is **not linear**, therefore a linear operator cannot ever act as such a scalar on a nontrivial subspace. For me, this means that the notions of eigenspace, eigenvalue, and hence of spectrum, have no meaning in this context. Also, even over the complex numbers (where all this makes sense) minimal polynomials of triangular matrices do not have to be irreducible, so what you ask for seems unreasonable.

Comment: Oh yes. I have made a mistake. Thanks so much. I edit this.

Comment: You did not answer to any of the points I raised, though you softened your stance on irreducibility. To begin with, how do you define the spectrum of a square matrix over $\Bbb H$? And how do you define its minimal polynomial?